# How to open a local excel sheet for editing on button click in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

I am using electron fro developing an application in which I need to open the local excel file on button click so help me out with this.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! [Right now, your question looks like a „can I haz codes?“-question](https://can-i-haz.codes) what is off-topic on SO. Either follow the steps on the first link, read **[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** or visit **[the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)**. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
var Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
Excel.Visible = true;
Excel.Workbooks.Open("teste.xlsx");
```

Comment: On IE it is just opening excel not the specified file and for the other browsers not even opening excel.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code . also , you can simple search in google and find your question .

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
      function test() {
        var Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
        Excel.Visible = true;
        Excel.Workbooks.Open("teste.xlsx");
      }
    </script>
```

```html
<html>

  <body>

    <form name="form1">
      <input type=button onClick="test()" value="Open File">
      <br><br>
    </form>

   
  </body>
</html>
```